# Supporting custom interval range for RangeSlider component

Tags: reactivesearch

I am using RangeInput component of reactivesearch, datafield values are ranging from 1 to 1M but most of the records within 0-1000 so the histogram display a single line. Is it possible to provide different intervals instead of single number.
I need intervals [0, 10, 50, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]

Comment: You can make use of `stepValue` prop and set it to the interval you want

Answer (score 0):

You can add this kind of props to your Range Components

```
stepValue={1}
showHistogram={true}
interval={2}
```

This can be used for real-time value show for rangeinput components this is missing on documentation

```
tooltipTrigger="always"
```

Also If you need more information about rangeinput components props please check this documentation

https://docs.appbase.io/docs/reactivesearch/v3/range/rangeinput/